# Determining what "Expected:in" refers too with for loop in Python

Tags: python-2.7

So I have the following code

```
    base = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ("
    lineCount = 0
    tableFieldNames = dataArray['titleRow']

    **for titleRow as tableFieldNames:**
        if some_list[-1] == titleRow:
            base = base + titleRow
        else:
            base = base + titleRow + ","

    base = base + ") VALUES "
```

where the bolded part gives an error "Invalid Syntax" and pypex's eclipse plugin gives a bit more verbose "Excepted:in" for the bolded text. What is throwing me is what that refers too. I've included a : at the end of the for loop declaration, and the array that it refers too is valid. Plus I have a for loop after this block of code that gives no such strange error.

Has anyone ran into such a thing, and found a way to resolve it (and even to make the parse errors more verbose?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `for titleRow in tableFieldNames:` (**in**, not **as**).

Comment: Interesting. My research didn't net that there would could be a variance in what could be used there. Lousy search skills.